# gatsby image svg not found

Tags: svg, gatsby

When trying to load an SVG image this way:

```
export const query = graphql`
    query {
        fileName: file(relativePath: { eq: "logo_large.svg" }) {
            childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 1060) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null`

If I try the exact same but with a .jpg or .png image, it works, so the relative path must be correct.
Any thing I should have in special consideration with SVG's?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? Running into the same issue!

Comment: @Ekaterina Yes I did, svg are not supported by this plugin for obvious reasons, they are vectorial and automatically adjust their size without the need of plugin like this one

Comment: yea that makes sense! how do you get the svg images then / how do you have them not go through the plugin?

Comment: I import them the good old way with a standard `html` image tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG are not supported by this plugin for obvious reasons, they are vectorial and automatically adjust their size without the need of plugin like this one

Answer (score 25):

> "SVG are not supported by this plugin for obvious reasons, they are
>   vectorial and automatically adjust their size without the need of
>   plugin like this one"

Correct. If you want to handle multiple types like png + jpg + svg you have to dynamically handle it with gatsby-image or not. You solve this by adding extension and publicURL in your GraphQL query:

```
  ...
  image {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 92) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
    extension
    publicURL
  }
  ...
```

Add this to your image component:

```
  // svg support
  if (!childImageSharp && extension === 'svg') {
    return <img style={imageStyle} src={publicURL} alt={alt} />
  }
```

Credit goes to [andresmrm](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10297#issuecomment-464834529) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks mate :) made my ~day~ night

Comment: A trick for others if you don't want to use `if`: `{ !childImageSharp && extension === 'svg' && <img ... /> }`

Comment: Don't forget to add loading="lazy" for img tag

Comment: Annoyingly, this generates a warning for every SVG, and I can't find a good way to suppress the warning: `warn You can't use childImageSharp together with some.svg — use publicURL instead. The childImageSharp portion of the query in this file will return null: index.js`

Comment: Ah, found the way to suppress the warning. In the `gatsby-transformer-sharp` config options, add `checkSupportedExtensions: false`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question with accepted answer but I thought I might add another solution for others' benefit. I found this solution at: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10297

```
import yourSVG from './logo_large.svg'

const Home = () => <><img src={yourSVG} /></>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps, but If you are looking for a generic and dynamic Image component that takes a custom file name and acts accordingly I've put together this:

This approach considers that you have an `images` folder inside your `src` folder where you have all your images.

```
const Image = ({ filename, alt }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        images: allFile {
          edges {
            node {
              relativePath
              name
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {

      // Handles SVG extension
      const extension = filename.match(/[^\\]*\.(\w+)$/)[1]
      if (extension === "svg") {
        return <img src={require(`../images/${filename}`)} alt={alt}/>
      }

      // Finds your image among all
      const image = data.images.edges.find(n => {
        return n.node.relativePath.includes(filename)
      })

      if (!image) {
        return null
      }
      return (
        <Img alt={alt} fluid={image.node.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
      )
    }}
  />
)
```

Be careful that this is **not** optimized and queries for all of your images. If you are trying to optimize performance in every way possible this isn't the best way to go.