# How to include gifs in yaml for gatsbyjs?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm sourcing data from yaml files and one of the field is a path to a gif file:

```
  name: Refer A Medical Specialist
  summary: Machine learning web app that refers a medical specialist depending on user's symptoms
  tags: [React, Node.js, MySQL, Redis]
  image: images/diagnosis_app.gif
```

I'm using gatsby-transformer-yaml which was recommended in the [official docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/gatsby-image-tutorial/) and it works fine for jpg, png, but doesn't work for animated gifs.

Are there any other solutions I could use?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `gatsby-transformer-yaml` but `Gatsby-Image`. Gatsby-Image can only handle file types `png` + `jpg`.

For gif you need to use another component like the good old `img` tag.

You need to dynamically handle different file types. You can use the [solution from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628498/gatsby-image-svg-not-found/56086747#56086747) for for gifs as well:

GraphQL:

```
  ...
  image {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 500, quality: 92) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
    extension // you might have to adapt this to your yaml data source
    publicURL // you might have to adapt this to your yaml data source
  }
  ...
```

Add this to your image component:

```
  // svg support
  if (!childImageSharp && extension === 'gif') {
    return <img src={publicURL} alt={alt} />
  }
```